# GIT: How to move copy a Readme.md file from master to Branch?

Tags: git

I'm just learning to work in git, I created a branch from a master repo and modified the Readme.md, but now want to replace it from the master branch, could you please help me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+copy+file+from+different+branch

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing

```
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```

will update said file to `master`'s version.

---

Alternatively, in recent git versions there is a dedicated command for this, [git restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), for example :

```
git restore -s master -- path/to/file
```